# Spark Scala EMR Job fails to download file from S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, parquet, snappy

I have a spark scala job that keeps failing in AWS EMR production and one of the first errors that I keep seeing in my executors is this `Download failed error`. I've looked at these files in S3, I even copied the file to a lower environment and ran the same job against it and everything worked as expected. The lower environment has less data to process but other than that I'm not really sure why I'm running into this issue. The production folder does have a Glue Job that runs every hour and writes new data, but I tried running the emr job with the glue job paused and I still ran into this error. Other than that nothing new is being written and some of the files that are trying to be accessed are months old and have data present.

```
2021-05-20 00:40:15 ERROR S3FSInputStream:295 - Unable to recover reading from stream
2021-05-20 00:40:15 ERROR AsyncFileDownloader:91 - TID: 3497 - Download failed for file path: s3://bucket/folder/part-000.snappy.parquet, range: 0-20427, partition values: [empty row], isDataPresent: false
java.io.IOException: Unexpected end of stream pos=4, contentLength=20427
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3.S3FSInputStream.read(S3FSInputStream.java:296)
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.read(IOUtils.java:2454)
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.readFully(IOUtils.java:2537)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ByteBufferIOUtils.readFullyHeapBuffer(ByteBufferIOUtils.java:89)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ByteBufferIOUtils.readFully(ByteBufferIOUtils.java:53)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3.AbstractS3FSInputStream.readFullyIntoBuffers(AbstractS3FSInputStream.java:97)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.BufferedFSInputStream.readFullyIntoBuffers(BufferedFSInputStream.java:137)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataInputStream.readFullyIntoBuffers(FSDataInputStream.java:270)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.util.H1SeekableInputStream.readFullyIntoBuffers(H1SeekableInputStream.java:64)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader$ConsecutiveChunkList.readAll(ParquetFileReader.java:1181)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.readNextRowGroup(ParquetFileReader.java:806)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat$$anonfun$buildPrefetcherWithPartitionValues$1.apply(ParquetFileFormat.scala:634)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat$$anonfun$buildPrefetcherWithPartitionValues$1.apply(ParquetFileFormat.scala:576)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.AsyncFileDownloader.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$AsyncFileDownloader$$downloadFile(AsyncFileDownloader.scala:93)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.AsyncFileDownloader$$anonfun$initiateFilesDownload$2$$anon$1.call(AsyncFileDownloader.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.AsyncFileDownloader$$anonfun$initiateFilesDownload$2$$anon$1.call(AsyncFileDownloader.scala:72)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.AbortedException: 
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleInterruptedException(AmazonHttpClient.java:868)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:746)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:704)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:686)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:550)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:530)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:5140)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:5086)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1490)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3.lite.call.GetObjectCall.perform(GetObjectCall.java:24)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3.lite.call.GetObjectCall.perform(GetObjectCall.java:8)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3.lite.executor.GlobalS3Executor.execute(GlobalS3Executor.java:114)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3.lite.AmazonS3LiteClient.invoke(AmazonS3LiteClient.java:191)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3.lite.AmazonS3LiteClient.getObject(AmazonS3LiteClient.java:102)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3.GetObjectInputStreamWithInfoFactory.create(GetObjectInputStreamWithInfoFactory.java:63)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3.S3FSInputStream.open(S3FSInputStream.java:199)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3.S3FSInputStream.retrieveInputStreamWithInfo(S3FSInputStream.java:390)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3.S3FSInputStream.reopenStream(S3FSInputStream.java:377)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3.S3FSInputStream.read(S3FSInputStream.java:259)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.timers.client.SdkInterruptedException
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.checkInterrupted(AmazonHttpClient.java:923)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.afterAttempt(AmazonHttpClient.java:1073)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1196)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:802)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:770)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:744)
    ... 36 more
```

Comment: what is the size of each file?